Why choose enum over const if no enum features are used?
w3schools has this example:
enum StatusCodes {
  NotFound = 404,
  Success = 200,
  Accepted = 202,
  BadRequest = 400
} 

Why would you use enum, instead of a const, in this example? It has the same type checking and is not using enum increments.
const StatusCodes = {
  NotFound: 404,
  Success: 200,
  Accepted: 202,
  BadRequest: 400
};

Is there any reason anyone would choose this enum example in their code?

Does this answer your question? Enum vs As Const

StatusCodes.NotFound = 69; Whoops. Should at least declare it as const.

Should be: const StatusCodes = { ... } as const

the enum has various other features like

type constraint
can be initialized with a function

enum E {
 A = getA(),
 B = getB()
}


Various others also

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Can object values not be initialised with a function?!

Also #3 is... uh... that's not really anything.

enum provides several features over a const object which enhance type checking, code readability, and make managing sets of constants simpler.

Readability: enum names clearly indicate the set's purpose.
Type Safety: It automatically enforces values to be part of the defined set.
Reverse Mapping: Allows both forward and reverse mappings for numeric values.
Union Type Creation: Values form a union type for stronger type checks.
Initialization Options: Flexible initialization (eg. numeric increments, expressions).


"Flexible initialization" wouldn't be a problem for const objects, would it?
